# Nice pattern for evaluating an assert message after a test fails

Tags: java, junit

Let's say I have a JUnit test like:

```
Assert.assertTrue(complexResult.toString(), someMethod(in1, in2, complexResult)
```

If the test fails, my message will be a complexResult string BEFORE the interesting part of the test that calls someMethod, not the string view of my complexResult after the test failed.

Is there a better way than:

```
if (!someMethod(in1, in2, complexResult)) {
   Assert.fail(complexResult.toString());
}
```

?

Comment: I read your post three times without getting it. `complexResult` sounds like an "out" parameter for the method? Why not let it return by the method in question? All in all, this sounds like very hard to understand by third parties (maintenance issue!).

Comment: If the value you want to display depends on `someMethod` then you need to call `someMethod`, not quite sure how there would be a way around this.

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean result = someMethod(in1, in2, complexResult); 
assertTrue(complexResult.toString(), result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just pre-evaluate the parameter of the assert call.

```
boolean result = someMethod(in1, in2, complexResult);
Assert.assertTrue(complexResult.toString(), result);
```

This is more elegant than the fail approach.